Couchbase SQL++ Left Join Query with CASE acts as inner join
I have the following query :
SELECT i.id, i.docId, i.proId, i.invRecipientType
FROM pulse i
WHERE i.type = 'pulseInvoice'
  AND i.invRecipientType IN ['cpam', 'b2b', 'b2c']
  AND i.orgId = 'pulseOrganization::S00001'
  AND i.ageId = 'pulseAgency::S00001'
  AND i.invStatus IN ['pending', 'error']
  AND i.sysActive = true
  AND i.invRecordingDate >= '2024-06-01' 
  AND i.invRecordingDate <= '2024-06-07'

It returns 9 rows as follows :
[
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::isl98829abd50231111efa73e4311e980c8e3",
    "docId": null,
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "b2c"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::enugl9e03791024ab11efa035dffe4b27df14",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::FRMS10002116811",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::z0rty6df5e850f58211eeac6b8d2531aa0da6",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::dpslc5f92b910a3b511e9a792a35b05d738a1",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::s4r3249dc43c0cbe711eeb25455d694fb3241",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::dpslc5f92b910a3b511e9a792a35b05d738a1",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::a2jic16022bd0226f11ef9c075de3aecc5009",
    "docId": null,
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::uw2o015f07890226f11ef9c075de3aecc5009",
    "docId": null,
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::wnw7o6dd806c0927f11eeb9215f9ff36c9f4c",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::dpslc5f92b910a3b511e9a792a35b05d738a1",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::bpvi8c99ce980180d11efa0cf07229265c17d",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::dpslc5f92b910a3b511e9a792a35b05d738a1",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::q556cbc7bcea024ac11efad1c19ce67df01f1",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::FRMS10002116811",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  }
]

If I add a left join with a CASE WHEN it seems to act as an inner join and excludes some rows :
SELECT i.id, i.docId, i.proId, i.invRecipientType
FROM pulse i
LEFT JOIN pulse p ON META(p).id = (CASE WHEN i.proId  THEN i.proId ELSE i.docId END)
WHERE i.type = 'pulseInvoice'
  AND i.invRecipientType IN ['cpam', 'b2b', 'b2c']
  AND i.orgId = 'pulseOrganization::S00001'
  AND i.ageId = 'pulseAgency::S00001'
  AND i.invStatus IN ['pending', 'error']
  AND i.sysActive = true
  AND i.invRecordingDate >= '2024-06-01' 
  AND i.invRecordingDate <= '2024-06-07'

I now get only 6 results, those with null docId and proId are excluded.
[
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::enugl9e03791024ab11efa035dffe4b27df14",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::FRMS10002116811",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::z0rty6df5e850f58211eeac6b8d2531aa0da6",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::dpslc5f92b910a3b511e9a792a35b05d738a1",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::s4r3249dc43c0cbe711eeb25455d694fb3241",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::dpslc5f92b910a3b511e9a792a35b05d738a1",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::wnw7o6dd806c0927f11eeb9215f9ff36c9f4c",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::dpslc5f92b910a3b511e9a792a35b05d738a1",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::bpvi8c99ce980180d11efa0cf07229265c17d",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::dpslc5f92b910a3b511e9a792a35b05d738a1",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  },
  {
    "id": "pulseInvoice::q556cbc7bcea024ac11efad1c19ce67df01f1",
    "docId": "pulseDoctor::FRMS10002116811",
    "proId": null,
    "invRecipientType": "cpam"
  }
]

Am I missing something ? If I specify the left join on i.docId or i.proId only, it returns the 9 rows, but combining it with the CASE filters them out.
Thanks

I can't speak to the behavior since I've not used couchbase. It does feel like this should work, or at the very least, shouldn't be filtering your results. My guess is that the NULL results in that CASE expression are leading to this odd behavior and that you will likely have better luck using something like: ON META(p).id = IFMISSINGORNULL(i.proId, i.docID, 9999999) just to avoid NULL coming through in the left-table of the join condition .

There seems some bug. In mean time try this
select i.id, i.docId, i.proId, i.invRecipientType
FROM pulse i
LEFT JOIN pulse p ON KEYS IFMISSINGORNULL(i.proId, i.docId)
WHERE i.type = 'pulseInvoice'
and i.invRecipientType IN ['cpam', 'b2b', 'b2c']
and i.orgId = 'pulseOrganization::S00001'
and i.ageId = 'pulseAgency::S00001'
and i.invStatus IN ['pending', 'error']
and i.sysActive = true
and i.invRecordingDate >= '2024-06-01'
and i.invRecordingDate <= '2024-06-07';

